# Route network traffic back to the same wire

Tags: networking, routing, wireshark

I would like to monitor outgoing traffic from my wi-fi connected phone using Wireshark on my Windows desktop. I changed default gateway on the phone to the IP of the desktop and Wireshark can now see connection requests sent from the phone. The problem is that these packets get dropped at this point. I would like to configure windows to act as a real gateway and forward those packets to the actual router so that connection is made and can be monitored.
What do I need to do to make this work?